# VBA Ctrl+A to select all content in a page by Selenium WebDriver

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

I saw a similar thread on Java but I am not familiar with that language so need a solution for VBA- suppose I want to press ctrl+A to select all content in a website using selenium:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim shell: Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

driver.Start "firefox", "http://www.espnfc.com/gamecast/statistics/id/376930  /statistics.html"
driver.setImplicitWait 5000
driver.Open "/"
shell.SendKeys "^a"

End sub
```

However this only highlights the URL. What is the best way to select all the content in the webpage and then copy it (ctrl +a and ctrl+ c)? ALso are there any references I need?

I've been looking for a good guide to selenium keys on google but have been struggling so far...

Comment: Before you send your Ctrl+A command, make sure you're focusing on the `body` of the webpage. I'm not familiar with the VBA bindings but it would likely be similar to `driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//body"));`. That will then mean the ctrl+a is applied to the webpage rather than the browser.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to point to the body, the syntax has got to be wrong- I tried driver.findElementByXpath("/html/body") and it still can't seem to do it...

Comment: Can you locate any other element on the page?

Comment: Think I've managed to do it using a CSS selector. Seems pertty difficult navigating on VBA though, wish I could do Java!

Comment: Good to hear! Too bad you have to use VBA, until today I didn't even know there were VBA bindings for Webdriver.

Comment: Another issue now, after I've copied the data I don't seem to be able to paste it in a cell- I keep getting range of class method fail, I think it is because there is nothing in the clipboard. If I paste it manually with my mouse there isn't a problem- any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I would start a new question with that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.getBodyText`? I tested it once and it worked fine:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim shell: Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
dim Body as string

driver.Start "firefox", "http://www.espnfc.com/gamecast/statistics   /id/376930  /statistics.html"
driver.setImplicitWait 5000
driver.Open "/"
Body=driver.getBodyText

End sub
```

You can then 'paste' into a spreadsheet via `cells(1,1)=Body` or back into a webpage element via `driver.findElementById("ElementNameHere").SendKeys Body`